# Backup docker windows RUNNING container

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I run some Docker Windows containers. I'm searching for some way to backup these containers, while they're **running**. But when I try to use standart ways to backup containers, I get such errors:

```
PS C:\Users\roza> docker commit 908d6334d554
Error response from daemon: windows does not support commit of a running container
PS C:\Users\roza> docker export 908d6334d554 -o tar.tar
Error response from daemon: the daemon on this platform does not support export of a container
```

Why I cannot commit/export **running** Windows containers?

Is there some (maybe non-standart and very tricky, maybe with usage of external tools) way to create backup of such containers?

Comment: Not sure if there are limitation on windows container. But you can try `docker pause <id>` and then `docker commit <id>` and see if it helps

Comment: Actually, I just get another error:
Error response from daemon: Cannot pause container 908d6334d5548f09ba6d3eeac5b38f56025c44b7056ef56c39edae06c003c252: container 908d6334d5548f09ba6d3eeac5b38f56025c44b7056ef56c39edae06c003c252 encountered an error during Pause: failure in a Windows system call: The request is not supported. (0x32)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you want to hear but... 
In container world, backup of running containers should not be required.  If you lose something when the container exists, then the image should be better segmented.  Anything that must survive after the container is killed (log, assets, or even temp folders) should be mapped as volumes.  That will give you greater control over backup.

Answer (score 1):

A commit of a Windows container also involves stopping it first, then committing.   Another limitation is that VSS based apps won't interoperate with containers.   As the earlier answer suggested, the standard approach for containers is to simply spin up a new container from an image.

Answer (score 1):

Windows images from Microsoft (which is all Windows images) are licensed, and I believe part of that licensing means you cannot export the image. The lack of pause/unpause is because of the underlying implementation. Linux does a pause with cgroups which aren't on Windows. Only Windows HyperV containers support pause because they use a HyperV command to implement it.

---

That said, backing up anything in docker involves backing up 3 things:

- the image registry server
- the configuration for the container, preferably a docker-compose.yml file
- the volume data

You don't backup the containers themselves, they are ephemeral, treated like cattle. The volume data will be a filesystem directory, and you'll use your standard backup tools on this directory. If you cannot backup while your container is running, then stop the container first, and restart the container after the backup is complete.